# Jtable not updating with my abstracttablemodel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I am new at programming and am working on my first school assignment. I have written a gui that accepts input and outputs data in a jtable added to a jpaddedpane. When the table first appears it shows all the correct data. But when I enter new input the table won´t update. I am alsmot positive the problem lies with my implementation of AstractTableModel. Can someone please take a look and correct it for me asap? Thanks in advance.

ps. nh, vh, hNam, proc_1 and proc_ are integer, string, integer, string and string arrays respectively. They hold the data to be displayed in the table.

```
 public class TableModel extends AbstractTableModel  {
        int numRows;
        String colNames[] = { "NH", "Horse Names", "VH",
                              "Proc. I", "Proc. II" };        
        Object[][] obj;

        TableModel()  {
            super();
            numRows = fnh;
            obj = new Object[fnh][5];

            for( int i = 0; i < fnh; i++ )  {
              for ( int j = 0; j < 5; j++ ) {
                  if ( j == 0 ) 
                      obj[i][0] = (Integer)nh[i];
                  else if ( j == 1 )
                      obj[i][1] = (String)hNam[i];
                  else if ( j == 2 )
                      obj[i][2] = (Integer)vh[i];
                  else if ( j == 3 )
                      obj[i][3] =(String)proc_1[i];
                  else 
                      obj[i][4] =(String)proc_2[i];        
               }
           }
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount()  {
           return numRows;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount()  {
            return 5;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName( int c ) {
            return colNames[c];
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt( int r, int c )  {
            if ( c == 0 ) 
                return nh[r];
            else if ( c == 1 )
                return hNam[r];
            else if ( c == 2 )
                return vh[r] ;
            else if ( c == 3 )
                return proc_1[r];
            else
                return proc_2[r];    
        }   

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable( int r, int c )  {
            return true;
        }        

        public void setValueAt( Object[][] value, int r, int c )  {
               value = obj;
               fireTableCellUpdated( r, c );
             }            

        }    
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is where the issue is    `value = obj;`

In `setValueAt` method you are not setting the values to the respective `obj` value's. The way you are accessing the `getValueAt` similarly set the obtained value to the respective array position.

Use `ArrayList` instead of using arrays. You can easily access all the methods.

```
class TableData {       
    private String name;
    private String grade;
    private String subject;
    private String staff;
   // Add getters and setters.
}
```

This is an example of the TableModel using ArrayList.

```
class AllTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    List<TableData> tableData = new ArrayList<TableData>();

    Object[] columnNames = {"Name", "Grade", "Subject", "Staff"};

    public AllTableModel(List<TableData> data) {

        tableData = data;
    }

    public List<TableData> getTableData() {
        return tableData;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return columnNames[column].toString();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return tableData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        TableData data = tableData.get(rowIndex);
        switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0:
            return data.getName();
        case 1:
            return data.getGrade();
        case 2:
            return data.getSubject();
        case 3:
            return data.getStaff();
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        TableData data = tableData.get(rowIndex);
        switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0:
            data.setName(aValue == null ? null : aValue.toString());
        case 1:
            data.setGrade(aValue == null ? null : aValue.toString());
        case 2:
            data.setSubject(aValue == null ? null : aValue.toString());
        case 3:
            data.setStaff(aValue == null ? null : aValue.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I am lost Che. Could you re-write me those two methods so I can better understand you?

Comment: @user2143292 Use `List` instead of arrays. You can easily access method.